# Extract part of Wicket form in a reusable panel

Tags: wicket

1 year ago, i ported an existing application from older wicket to version 8, without too much thinking how it works.
Now, i want to understand a bit better to simplify the code i found...

For this, in a big form page, i have code like the sample below. 
The "situationdiv?"'s have the same structure, i want to make it a reusable panel.

I wanted to pass the model "CLBX.?" to the panel constructor, but i can't find the good way to do it.
Is there another better solution ?

Please help me find how to do this...

```
<form wicket:id="form">
    <input name="check1" id="check1" type="checkbox" wicket:id="IGEN1ST"
            value="1" oninput="visibiliteTxtArea('1')"/>
    <div id="body1div"><textarea id="body1" wicket:id="T01K1ST01" name="body1"
                                maxlength="1000" control_length="1"
                                style="display: none" rows="10"></textarea></div>
    ....
    <div id="situationdiv1">
        <h2><wicket:message key="F8.Mot2">Durée de la situation</wicket:message></h2>
        <wicket:message key="F8.Per">Période du</wicket:message>
        <input type="text" class="text date" name="startDate0" id="DPERBEG0"
               wicket:id="CLBX.0.DPERBEG" value=""/>
        <wicket:message key="F8.Tot2">au</wicket:message>
        <input type="text" class="text date" name="endDate0"
               wicket:id="CLBX.0.DPEREND" id="DPEREND0"
               value=""/>
        ......
    </div>
    <div id="situationdiv2">
        <h2><wicket:message key="F8.Mot2">Durée de la situation</wicket:message></h2>
        <wicket:message key="F8.Per">Période du</wicket:message>
        <input type="text" class="text date" name="startDate1" id="DPERBEG1"
               wicket:id="CLBX.1.DPERBEG" value=""/>
        <wicket:message key="F8.Tot2">au</wicket:message>
        <input type="text" class="text date" name="endDate1"
               wicket:id="CLBX.1.DPEREND" id="DPEREND1"
               value=""/>
        ......
    </div>
    ....
</form>
```

```
public class MyWebPage extends WebPage {
    //Data is filled/organized from DB.
    //Structure: Map<String, Object>
    //mostly <String, String> or <String, Integer>
    //sometimes anything else like <"CLBX", ArrayList<Map<String, Object)>> (for situations)
    //       and in these, only <String, String> or <String, Integer>
    public MyWebPage(Map<String, Object> data) {
        this.init(data, readonly);
    }
    private void init(Map<String, Object> data, boolean readonly) {
        Form<String> form = new Form<String>("form") {
            @Override
            protected void onSubmit() {
                super.onSubmit();
                log.debug("form submit");
            }
        }
        add(form);
        form.setDefaultModel(new CompoundPropertyModel(data));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `FormComponentPanel` to reuse the common form components.

`FormComponentPanel` is a FormComponent that could have its own markup, like a Panel. As such, it could have FormComponent children, like TextField, DropdownChoice, etc.